# Placing a view above the DrawerLayout (above the drawers)

Tags: android, view, drawerlayout

Is it possible to place a `View` above the whole `DrawerLayout`? So the view stays above the drawers even if they are open?

Comment: Do you mean vertically above, or z-ordered above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to place a `View` above the whole `DrawerLayout`?

Yes. Consider the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <DrawerLayout>
    <FrameLayout>
      <!-- the content comes here -->
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- one or two drawer views comes here - displayed over content-->
  </DrawerLayout>

  <!-- any views that are here will be painted even over the drawers -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: damn, I read somewhere that DrawerLayout needs to be a rootview and didn't even bother to check if thats really the case. thx

Comment: No, it doesn't. In fact this is a great way to do an overlay toolbar.